What's the dual of an LP in its general form?
For an LP written as
\begin{align}
    \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} ~~~ &c^\top x \\
    s.t. ~~& l^{s}\leq Ax \leq u^{s},\\
        &l^{x}\leq x \leq u^{x}
\end{align}
how can we get its dual quickly?
In this case, can we convert one constraint in the primal to one variable in the dual and convert one variable to one constraint? Or do we have to add more variables in the dual for each constraint and variable with two bounds in the primal?

What types is your problem? ($LP$ or $MIP$ as you tagged mixed-integer)

LP. There is no integer variable.

https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/duality.html#lagrangian-and-the-dual-problem Example 8.4

@andy, to start, I think this would also be a good place.

Related: Finding the dual problem of a minimum problem
